# Simulate loading effect in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm doing a process via AJAX after clicking a button

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myButton").click(function(){
            //Set loading text
            $(this).html("Loading...");

            //Do the ajax call
            $.ajax(....


            //Finaly reset my button text.
            $(this).html("Save Changes");
      }); 

 });
```

This is working in Firefox but, when I test it on Chrome and IE it does not work.
Can anybody help me?

I also tried to launch a modal with the loading message and then close it, but it never appears, only in Firefox.

Comment: Does the html of the button change at all?

Comment: No, I've removed the last line [$(this).html("Save Changes");]
 and the button changed its text to "Loading...", but just after the ajax call is done.

Comment: The button is not generated on the fly, just is hidden, I've tried the on('click',...  but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the button reset text in the callbacks.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: ...
    success: function (result) {
        //Finaly reset my button text.
                $(this).html("Save Changes");

    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {
        //Finaly reset my button text.
                $(this).html("Save Changes");
    }
});
```

Comment: I found that I've the async:false property seted, put the action in callback works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The restore should be in one of the Ajax callbacks (probably `complete`). Otherwise it just resets it immediately, as the Ajax call is asynchronous.